# Why span of two linearly indepedent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ gives a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S=\{(1,2,-1),(2,0,1)\}.$ Then $L(S)=\{\alpha \cdot(1,2,-1)+\beta\cdot(2,0,1):\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}\}.$

$L(S)=\{(\alpha+2\beta,2\alpha,-\alpha+\beta):\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

How will I understand that $L(S)$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: What is your definition of "a plane"?

Comment: Check that any vector $(x,y,z)$ in Span S satisfies $2x-3y-4z=0$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician It is not clear to me how to define a plane using vectors.

Comment: (i) One way is to say it's all linear combinations of two L.I. vectors. (ii) Another is to say it's the set of vectors perpendicular to some fixed vector, the "normal".  In case (ii) you can get the normal by taking the vector product of the two vectors in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from this specific case, you can always find $a,b,c$ such that $ax + by + cz = 0$, which is also the plane equation; because there are only two variables, i.e. $\alpha, \beta$, and x,y,z coordinates are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need to come up with a definition of a plane before a clear answer can be provided. Are you happy with the cartesian plane "from highschool", with marks along the x-axis and y-axis? Thats precisely the plane you'd get from the span of vectors $\mathbf u=\binom{0}{1},\mathbf v= \binom{1}{0}$. A point with coordinates $\binom{a}{b}$ in the cartesian plane is nothing more than the linear combination $a \mathbf u + b \mathbf v$. [image]